# Get current credentials to access other REST service

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having a problem with Spring MVC + Spring security (both 3.2.8 versions). Well, I have a *REST* service which returns all the equipment stored in my application in xml format. That's how I call it:

```
{baseUrl}/service/equipment
```

And that's methods signature, where an `EquipmentExchangeSet` entity is returned. This entity uses java xml binding annotations.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "equipment", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = XML_JSON_HEADERS, produces = {
        XML, JSON })
@ResponseBody
public EquipmentExchangeSet getEquipment() {

}
```

What I want to do now is to take that file and process it with xsl styles in order to get an output HTML or a PDF later on. So I've implemented this Spring service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/equipment/format/html", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE })
@ResponseBody
public String getEquipmentHTML() throws TransformerException, IOException {
    /* Create a TransformerFactory object */
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    /* Get the incoming XSLT file */
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(
            "equipment.xsl"));
    URL xmlServiceUrl = new URL(
            "http://localhost:8080/myapp/service/equipment/");
    /* Get the XML file and apply the XSLT transformation to convert to HTML */
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xmlServiceUrl.openStream()),
            new StreamResult(os));
    return os.toString();
}
```

This accesses the url of the first service, gets the xml content and processes it to get stylish output HTML content. Everything works like a charm when removing the Spring security constraints, however, I need them to let only the logged users access the services. That's how my spring security configuration is configured for web services:

```
<http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" pattern="/service/**"
    use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/service/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="restSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="restFailureHandler"
        login-processing-url="/service/j_spring_security_check" />

    <logout />
</http>
```

This configuration permits access only for already authenticated users. However, when I try to make the request from the Spring service itself, I get a *401 (not authorized)* code. Is there a way to retrieve the credentials from the service or execute that request in kind of same context?

Comment: It sounds like you need to investigate a SSO (Single Sign-On) solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would redesign the Controller method and split the actual logic that produces the XML in a service. That way you can inject the service in the other controller and call it without actually making an additional request to the same application. It is actually bad practice to make internal requests like `localhost:8080/...` because that code will break as soon as you deploy on a different port.

```
@Service
public class EquipmentService {

    public InputStream getEquipmentAsXml(){
        ....
    }
}

@Controller
public class EquipmentController {

    @Autowired
    private EquipmentService equipmentService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/equipment/format/html", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE })
    @ResponseBody
    public String getEquipmentHTML() throws TransformerException, IOException {
        /* Create a TransformerFactory object */
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        /* Get the incoming XSLT file */
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(
        "equipment.xsl"));

        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(equipmentService.getEquipmentAsXml()),
        new StreamResult(os));
        return os.toString();
    }
}
```

That way you not only circumvent the whole problem with the authentication but also make your code more reusable and eliminate a bug.

Comment: `localhost:8080` was just to provide a kickoff example of what I want to achieve. I usually manage host names as enviroment properties, so this value would be injected in a real case. The problem with your workaround is I'm not sure I could return such an `InputStream` also in the Controller when I want to get them in xml format. Actually I use jaxb for that conversion. My idea was to take advantage of being currently able to access the data in xml format via HTTP. I modified my question for further explanation of my case.

Comment: What is the signature of your `Controller` that produces the XML? Maybe the service can produce the list of JAVA objects. Then the one controller transforms it to XML and the other to HTML. Actually, this sounds like a typical case for content negotiation, as the underlying model is the same. Check https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc. You could implement the custom views that transform the data to HTML and PDF respectively.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to stick with this design - Spring stores the authentication details in the session. You'll need to copy the session from the current request to the internal request, for which you'll probably need something more than `URL`, maybe apache `HTTPClient`.

Comment: I've updated my example with method's signature. Producing Java objects in the service should be the way, but as I'm required to obtain also the xml file for doing the xslt transformation, I was thinking about using my current API method which returns the raw xml. That way I should be able to obtain either the raw xml and that xml processed into html. But maybe it's an overkill.

Comment: I think for your case it is best to implement and register 2 custom `MessageConverter`s - one for HTML and one for PDF. If you have the logic for producing the HTML and PDF from XML, convert the model to XML first (see `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`). That way you will have only one controller method that handles the requests for the equipment and a few different rendering views.